# how to check if page QObject has been deleted in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to test code on a page that auto-closes after a form has been submitted.

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.evaluate(function() {
    //fill form and submit
 });

 if(page !== null) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      //do something
    });
 }
```

Each time I try to check if(page !== null) I get an error stating

```
 Error: cannot access member `evaluate' of deleted QObject
```

instead of running my code when page is not null. What am I missing here? I just want to check if variable page or page's QObject has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using this code to check if page is "dead":

```
 if(page == undefined || page == null || (page+'')=='null'){
   console.log('page is dead')
}
```

Comment: Seems like the only way to check if a QObject has been deleted is the last option: `myObject + '' === 'null'`. Related bug report [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13631).